# What should be switching voltage rating of relay in a 380VAC 3 phase system?

Tags: ac, relay, high-voltage, generator, three-phase

I am hooking up a system where there is 2 sources of power available. One source is the grid power, and the other is a generator. The grid provides me with 3-phase 380VAC with a neutral wire; and on the other hand, the generator provides me with 3-phase 380VAC BUT no neutral wire. I am using a SPDT relay on each phase, and all relays are controlled through a common signal coming from a micro-controller. So, all three relays are switched at the same time. The load is a battery charger that has a 3-phase input and does not accept a neutral wire, just three hot wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foXM8F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, my main question is when I am looking for a relay suited for my need, should I look for relays that have a switching voltage rating of 220VAC or 380VAC?

The confusing part for me is that if I measure voltage between one phase and neutral the voltage is 220VAC, but 380VAC line to line. So, I am not sure whether I need a relay with a switching voltage rating of 220VAC or 380VAC!

Thanks

Comment: "*I am using a SPDT relay on each phase ...*" This is a really bad idea. Have you considered the possible failure modes?

Comment: May I ask why it is a bad idea? I have not considered the possible failure modes! What do you recommend as an alternative solution?

Comment: It leaves the possibility that one of the relays doesn't operate, leaving two of the lines connected to one of the supplies. You now have a singe phase supplying the charger - there's a good chance that it will have detection of this and will not operate, but why not use a three pole contactor?

Comment: The right way to do this is with a pair of mechanically and electrically interlocked three pole contactors (With auxiliary contacts fitted to provide the electrical interlocking) such that it is physically impossible for one set of contacts to close until the others have fully opened. Depending on where you are located this thing may need to be certified by someone, in which case buying a " Three phase Automatic transfer switch" is the way to bet.

Comment: @PhilG Oh I would be more than happy to use a three pole double throw contractor, but the problem is I have not been able to find one!

Comment: @DanMills Thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely look into that model.

Comment: But let's say I followed all the safety rules, and I have a solid system. What should be the switching voltage rating of my relays/contactors? 220VAC or 380VAC?

Comment: @MarkWright, I would actually suggest 440VAC, unless your generator is synchronized with the grid.  As drawn, there's nothing stopping Grid_P1 from being 180 degrees out of phase with Gen_P1 (and same for P2 and P3) for a 440V difference.

Comment: The proper equipment as described by Dan Mills would be rated for the purpose intended at 380 volts.

Comment: You're not that likely to find a 3PDT contactor of any size (I'm guessing the risk of flashover makes them difficult to do), the automatic transfer switch that @DanMills describes is usually a pair of 3PNO contactors in a box, wired such that only one of them can be on at any one time. The electrical interlocking is dealt with by auxiliary contacts (often microswitches) that will prevent coil current to one contactor unless the other is open. You then just have a relay or switch that selects which source you want - you haven't described how you intend this to operate.

Comment: @PhilG and the mechanical interlocking is usually built into the base of the contactor assembly. A rewired reversing contactor will often get it done and has all the mechanical interlocking in place already.

Comment: @DanMills I looked into 3-phase Automatic Transfer Switch, and that is exactly what I need. One last question I have is that do you know where I could buy them from? I looked at Galco, and some other online sellers, but they sell manual transfer switches, rather than automatic.Do you know where I could buy a 3-phase minimum 380VAC 40A ATS? Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @MarkWright What country? I would start by speaking to your generator vendor as they will probably be able to either sort it or tell you who to speak to, and can also provide useful things like automatic generator start controllers and generator starting battery float charge systems (And oil heaters if required).  This is totally standard data centre stuff.  You may wish to take advice as well as to how often you need to run the generator on load to get best reliability (A machine that has been left standing for two years will very likely NOT start when you need it to).

Comment: @DanMills I live in Canada. Good point, I will talk to the generator vendor to get more information. Again, thanks for your help. I don't see an option to choose your comment as an answer, but if you do have the option, please mark your first comment as the answer :)

Comment: @Mark: Just a caution. Questions about product recommendations and where to buy them are off-topic and will get your question closed very quickly. See [Help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is with a pair of mechanically and electrically interlocked three pole contactors (With auxiliary contacts fitted to provide the electrical interlocking) such that it is physically impossible for one set of contacts to close until the others have fully opened.

Depending on where you are located this thing may need to be certified by someone, in which case buying a "Three phase Automatic transfer switch" is the way to bet.

If building your own a "Three pole mechanically interlocked motor reversing contactor" (It is actually a pair of contactors with an interlock module) with an NC aux contact on each half can usually be easily modified to do what you need.

I would start by speaking to your generator vendor as they will probably be able to either supply a packaged solution it or tell you who to speak to, and can also provide useful things like automatic generator start controllers and generator starting battery float charge systems (And oil heaters if required).

This is totally standard data centre stuff. You may wish to take advice as well as to how often you need to run the generator on load to get best reliability (A machine that has been left standing for two years will very likely NOT start when you need it to).

Answer put together from a comment thread that ran long.